# jQuery : how to switch case when requesting JSON info

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm a total novice with jQuery (and javascript in general!), so with that in mind please be merciful! :)

I'm trying to pull information from a JSON database, to do that I've created a search box and I've managed to source a solution for requesting the data that seems to work perfectly if I type in the EXACT thing I am looking for. But obviously I would like to have it so that the user doesn't need to worry about case matching.

I figured the most sensible thing to do would be to use some sort of fuzzy search but so far my efforts have resulted in exactly squat!

**Here is the function that pulls the data:**

```js
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

**And here is the nightmare that is my attempt to deal with that information:**

```js
$.getJSON("json/AllSets.json",function(hearthStoneData){
  $('.submit').click(function(){
   var searchValue = $('#name').val();
   var inputValue = searchValue.toUpperCase();
   var returnValue = getObjects(hearthStoneData, "name", searchValue);
   var outputValue = returnValue.toString();
   console.log(outputValue);
  });
 });
```

Does anybody have any advice on where I'm going wrong? I think I've gone waaaay off the beaten path with all the variables in the last part, I was trying to set both user input and the returned data to upper case but I think the fuzzy search option would make more sense?

Anyway, I appreciate any help you can offer, thanks for taking the time to read through what I imagine is some very confused code :P

Comment: I think you may want `objects.push(obj[i]);` instead of `objects.push(obj);`

Comment: good spot! that improved the result too :D thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution is to test a match using only lowercase in the val check:

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key].toLowerCase() == val.toLowerCase()) {
            objects.push(obj[i]);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

//edited to include harvtronix' input.

Comment: That worked like a charm! thanks so much this was driving me insane! :D

Comment: Glad it worked. @Harvtronix may be on to something though. Check your output.

Comment: Oh and for future reference "switch case" is an entirely different operation using the 'switch' and 'case' keywords and booleans. This was a string matching issue. :)